# Google apps marketplace App only for specific domain

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I want to create an app only applicable for one or two domains. And i am trying to follow the doc here, https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing

I have done all the steps except 7th step, as i don't want it to be published on marketplace.

Also i have got an url after publishing the app in webstore, but when i click on the link it only allow me to add as a chrome extension, but nothing as an market place app?

So now, how can i add it to my domain and any other specific domain i want?

Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks,

Ramesh.V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will actually want to publish but make sure you configure the visibility options correctly. In the Developer Dashboard you can make a listing available to your domain, a Google Group of testers, etc. In order to restrict to a domain, the admin creating the listing must be a member of the domain. So in order to restrict to more than one domain, I would recommend creating a unique listing per domain. Many system integrators take advantage of this by creating unique branding per domain. Alternatively you could use the Google Group route if that's all you need.